Bot Framework: 'access_token' Error When Sending Messages in Teams Bot Using Python
I'm building a Teams bot using the Bot Framework SDK for Python, integrated with FastAPI. The bot is supposed to send periodic updates to users every 60 seconds after they send an initial message. However, I'm facing issues with sending messages due to an access_token error.
When I use turn_context within on_message_activity, the bot responds correctly to the user's initial message. But when trying to send periodic updates outside of on_message_activity, I'm encountering the access_token error.
I'm aware that a new TurnContext needs to be created for each conversation, but I'm unsure how to properly implement this. I've followed the necessary steps as far as I know, but the bot still isn't sending the periodic messages.
Code:
import asyncio
from botbuilder.core import ActivityHandler, TurnContext, MessageFactory, BotFrameworkAdapterSettings, BotFrameworkAdapter
from botbuilder.schema import Activity, ConversationReference
from botbuilder.core.teams import TeamsActivityHandler
from typing import Dict
from botframework.connector.auth import ClaimsIdentity, MicrosoftAppCredentials
from fastapi import APIRouter
import json

# Logging setup
# (Assuming a logger is properly configured)
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Bot settings
APP_ID = 'your-app-id-here'
APP_PASSWORD = 'your-app-password-here'

# Adapter configuration
CONFIGS = BotFrameworkAdapterSettings(APP_ID, APP_PASSWORD)
ADAPTER = BotFrameworkAdapter(CONFIGS)

# Router setup for FastAPI
router = APIRouter()

class NotifyBot(TeamsActivityHandler):
    def __init__(self, adapter):
        super().__init__()
        self.adapter = adapter
        self.conversation_references: Dict[str, ConversationReference] = {}
        self.scheduled_tasks: Dict[str, asyncio.Task] = {}
        logger.info("NotifyBot initialized")

    async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
        # Store conversation reference when user sends a message
        self.add_conversation_reference(turn_context.activity)

        # Extract the user ID from the incoming activity
        user_id = turn_context.activity.from_property.id

        # Send a response to acknowledge the user
        await turn_context.send_activity("Thanks for messaging me. I'll start sending you updates now.")

        # Start sending periodic messages if not already scheduled
        if user_id not in self.scheduled_tasks:
            logger.info(f"Scheduling periodic messages for user {user_id}")
            self.scheduled_tasks[user_id] = asyncio.create_task(self.send_periodic_messages(user_id))

    def add_conversation_reference(self, activity: Activity):
        # Add or update the conversation reference for a user
        conversation_reference = TurnContext.get_conversation_reference(activity)
        self.conversation_references[conversation_reference.user.id] = conversation_reference
        logger.info(f"Added conversation reference for user {conversation_reference.user.id}")

    async def send_periodic_messages(self, user_id: str):
        while True:
            try:
                # Send a message every 5 seconds
                await asyncio.sleep(60)
                await self.send_personal_message(user_id)
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                logger.info(f"Cancelled periodic messages for user {user_id}")
                break
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"Error sending periodic message to user {user_id}: {str(e)}")

    async def send_personal_message(self, user_id: str):
        conversation_reference = self.conversation_references.get(user_id)

        if conversation_reference:
            try:
                logger.info(f"Sending message to user {user_id}")

                # Use continue_conversation to send the message
                await self.adapter.continue_conversation(
                    bot_app_id=APP_ID,
                    reference=conversation_reference,
                    logic=lambda turn_context: asyncio.create_task(self.send_message_callback(turn_context, "Periodic update: hi!"))
                )

            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"Error sending message to user {user_id}: {str(e)}")
        else:
            logger.error(f"No conversation reference found for user {user_id}")

    async def send_message_callback(self, turn_context: TurnContext, message: str):
        try:
            await turn_context.send_activity(MessageFactory.text(message))
            logger.info(f"Message sent to {turn_context.activity.from_property.id}")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error sending message: {str(e)}")

Issues I'm Facing:

The bot successfully responds to the initial message in
on_message_activity, but it doesn't send the periodic messages every
60 seconds as intended.
When trying to send messages using continue_conversation, I receive
an 'access_token' error.
I'm concerned that the token used in the initial turn_context will
expire, and I need to create a new turn_context or properly handle
tokens, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

What I've Tried:

Ensured that APP_ID and APP_PASSWORD are correctly set.
Attempted to acquire a new access token using
MicrosoftAppCredentials, but I'm not sure if I'm implementing it
correctly.
Reviewed documentation and examples on how to use
continue_conversation and ClaimsIdentity, but still facing issues.

Questions:

How can I correctly send periodic messages to the user every 5
seconds?
How do I properly handle the access_token and ClaimsIdentity when
using continue_conversation?
Do I need to create a new TurnContext for each message, and if so,
how can I do that?

Any help or guidance on how to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated!
Additional Information:

I'm using the Bot Framework SDK for Python.
The bot is hosted using FastAPI.
The goal is to have the bot send updates to users periodically after
they initiate a conversation.


You can use proactive messaging for this, please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=python.
